# Put condition to andThen method of Completable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `Completable` created like this:

```
public Completable doCalulations() {
    return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
        //some calculations
    })
    .andThen(/*Here I want to sequentially execute another Completable*/);
}
```

After first `Completable` calls `onComplete` I want to execute sequentially another `Completable` based on some condition:

```
if (condition.check()) {
    return someCalculation(); //returns Completable
} else {
    return anotherCalculation(); //returns Completable
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `Completable.defer(() -> { /* your condition and returns here */})`.

Comment: To clarify: you are taking about 3 compietables?

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you, that is what I needed. You may post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `defer`:

```
public Completable doCalulations() {
    return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
        //some calculations
    })
    .andThen(
        Completable.defer(() -> {
            if (condition.check()) {
                return someCalculation(); //returns Completable
            } else {
                return anotherCalculation(); //returns Completable
            }
        })
    );
}
```